# How to move overlay item above mapview in android?

Tags: android, android-mapview, itemizedoverlay, currentlocation

I have to get current location continuously  and move overlayitem over mapview in android?
I have used following code to get current location for which i have to used different class for getting current location and implemenets its method but i am not able to get current location continuously above activity.

```
**CurentLocation.java**
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class CurrentLocation {
    Timer timer1;
    LocationManager lm;
    LocationResult locationResult;
    boolean gps_enabled=false;
    boolean network_enabled=false;

    public boolean getLocation(Context context, LocationResult result)
    {
        //I use LocationResult callback class to pass location value from MyLocation to user code.
        locationResult=result;
        if(lm==null)
            lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //exceptions will be thrown if provider is not permitted.
        try{gps_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}
        try{network_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}

        //don't start listeners if no provider is enabled
        if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled)
            return false;

        if(gps_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerGps);
        if(network_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerNetwork);
        timer1=new Timer();
        timer1.schedule(new GetLastLocation(), 20000);
        return true;
    }

    LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer1.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer1.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
             lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);

             Location net_loc=null, gps_loc=null;
             if(gps_enabled)
                 gps_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
             if(network_enabled)
                 net_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

             //if there are both values use the latest one
             if(gps_loc!=null && net_loc!=null){
                 if(gps_loc.getTime()>net_loc.getTime())
                     locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                 else
                     locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                 return;
             }

             if(gps_loc!=null){
                 locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                 return;
             }
             if(net_loc!=null){
                 locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                 return;
             }
             locationResult.gotLocation(null);
        }
    }

    public static abstract class LocationResult{
        public abstract void gotLocation(Location location);
    }
}
```

Main activity.java

```
public class ManinActivity extends MapActivity {

    double currentLatitude=666.563961600000000000;
    double currentLongitude=66666.334281799999980000;
    MapView mapView; 
    MapController mc;
    GeoPoint p;

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            //===========Call Current location==
            CurrentLocation myLocation = new CurrentLocation();
            myLocation.getLocation(this, locationResult);
                }

    LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult(){
                @Override
                public void gotLocation(Location location){
                    if(location!=null)
                    {
                    currentLatitude=location.getLatitude();
                    currentLongitude=location.getLongitude() ;

                    }
                }
            };

}
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Remove these lines in your  `LocationListener`

```
  lm.removeUpdates(this);
  lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
```

**Update**

also if you do not want to stop the timer then also remove this line in your  `LocationListener`

```
 timer1.cancel();
```

**more update**

you also need to remove these lines in your `GetLastLocation`  class

```
 lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
 lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
```